# Retrieve cookie from browser will work with php curl?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, web-scraping, http-headers

I have a simple php application that get prices from a website, but it is only working if I copy the `cookie` from the chrome browser request of the page. Can I simply copy/paste this `cookie` line in the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and it will work forever?

Also, It works perfectly when I set a proxy too. I don't know why. Can anyone explain me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have the contents of the cookie ( copied from your browser ), you have a few options if you are using curl with php
if the cookie rarely changes and/or if you have a simple script, you can embed the cookie in the script with CURLOPT_COOKIE as in the example.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, <COOKIE_STRING_CONTENT>);
```

It's the easiest way, but the caveat is every time the cookie changes, you need to update script.

If you need something more malleable, easier to update and maintain you can use this 2 directives CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR as bellow,

```
$cookieFile = "name_of_the_cookie_file_on_the_server"
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
```

What this does is instruct the script to load the cookie file, and stores changes on the same file ( if any ), this way if you ever need to update the contents of the cookie you just need to update de cookie file.

curl have a lot of nice options don't forget to read the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Hi @rafael, thanks a lot. I don't have a good knowledge about cookies. How do I know if this cookie is going to change? I simply copied the cookie header line of code from Chrome and used with `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "cookie: ..... ");`

Comment: A cookie always changes, it can take a few days (in case of cookies used for authentication purposes) to a few months or never (in case of web browser tracking cookies), I probably would use my first example while developing and change to my second example after testing

Comment: You can use curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "cookie: ..... ");
internally it's what curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, <COOKIE_STRING_CONTENT>); does, but i find it easier to read and maintain

Comment: I've tried adding cookiefile and cookiejar to my code, but now I'm getting a different page from what I get when I open via browser.

Comment: you need to make sure you are opening the right file in the right format for it to work